# Using web form results at client/browser side > input to python

Tags: javascript, python

I have created web pages with forms for input but I want to use that input at the client side and not pass it back to the server...

Setup:

- One Raspberry Pi (#4) running some python code controlling LEDs = client
- A second Raspberry Pi (#5) running webmin with apache server hosting html + javascript + CSS pages. Pages have switches, slider and time inputs. Eg.

***html***:

```
<button id="switch" type="button" onclick="toggle(standby)">
```

***javascript***:

```
function toggle() {
    if (standby==true) {    
        document.getElementById('button').classList.toggle('on');
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('button').classList.toggle('off');
    }
    standby = !standby;
}
```

This part works fine - by clicking on the button I can change its appearance (via the CSS file) and keep track of the button's on-off state using the 'standby' variable.

What I want to do is control the LED on RPi #4 via the browser without sending data back to the server on RPi #5.

Somehow, I need that 'standby' variable from the web page to be available to the python code, so it can turn on/off the LED (all I want for Christmas!)

All my searches point to data going back to the server (Flask, AJAX, CGI, etc.)

Many thanks!

Comment: If you're not using the server, why do you have a server?

Comment: Hi Boann, hopefully my question update explains things better... Suppose there are lots of lights in different houses/rooms that you want to control over the web... my web page (on my server) will provide a user interface - but the control message has to get from your web browser to your lights - I don't want those control signals coming back to my server, and you don't either!

Comment: I wouldn't want my use of my light switch being dependent on your server at all.

Comment: OK, good - you have the concept of controlling lights via web pages… 
My idea may be flawed - but are you saying every installation would need its own server and web pages? (Not everyone has that, and I know the time, effort and money to get there.) 
I just checked and it is possible to continue toggling the switch after the server is down - but not suggesting the web interface would be the only means of control.

Comment: If you have a communications path between the web browser and the switch boxes, which you need to have to do what you're trying to do anyway, then you just can serve the web page from the switch boxes without the separate server.

Comment: OK, I will have a go at driving my LEDs from the server side and then have a think on how to implement the switch box. 
Many thanks for your time and advice - much appreciated. (Is it best to delete my original question?)